# Getting maximum metric value over a period of latest 90 days only

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

I would like to find a way to add the maximum of a metrics on the last 90 days as a columns.

```
SELECT id1,
       id2,
       date,
       metric,
       MAX(metric) OVER(PARTITION BY id1, id2 WHERE date >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -90 DAY)) max_l90
FROM table
```

I was wondering about doing something like that but it does not works. I also tried to have a look at window functions but it seems that we can't insert conditions in it.

Does any one have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a conditional way by embedding a `CASE` expression inside the `MAX` function:

```
SELECT id1,
       id2,
       date,
       metric,
       MAX(CASE WHEN date >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -90 DAY)
                THEN metric 
           END) OVER(PARTITION BY id1, id2) max_l90
FROM table
```

Comment: Is there a way to consider dynamically the last 90 days from the "date" column ?

Comment: You need to create a view, that's gonna get you dynamic 90 days from the date column, because views are computed every time they're called in a `SELECT` statement, in a lazy way. If that's what you were looking for, you can use `CREATE VIEW <name_view> AS ` right before the `SELECT` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to filter the data for the last 90 days and then use the MAX function to get the maximum value of the metric for each id1 and id2

```
SELECT id1, id2, date, metric,
       (SELECT MAX(metric)
        FROM table t2
        WHERE t2.id1 = t1.id1 AND t2.id2 = t1.id2 AND t2.date >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -90 DAY)
       ) AS max_l90
FROM table t1;
```